# Mongoose Error: TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `Bt` is not a valid type at path `category`

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I took a break from working on this project and now that I am back, I receive an error that I never received before:
'TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `Bt` is not a valid type at path `category`. See [site] for a list of valid schema types.'

This is the bit of my code that is causing problem. I don't understand why something changed as I didn't modify the code.

```
const ProductSchema = new Schema(
  {
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    description: String,
    price: { type: Number, required: true },
    images: [{ type: String }],
    category: {
      type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Category",
      required: false,
    },
    properties: { type: Object },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

export const Product = models.Product || model("Product", ProductSchema);
```

Comment: In the error: `Bt is not a valid type` what is `Bt` referring to? `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` as the type will work just fine but it should really be `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId`. Have you accidentally typed `Bt` somewhere and saved it perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your question you are referencing the category into product schema so when referencing another schema in Mongoose, you would use **mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId** instead **mongoose.Types.ObjectId**.

```
category: {
  type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, // Make sure this line is correct
  ref: "Category",
  required: false,
},
```

Comment: I agree that `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` is the correct type definition but  `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` will work perfectly fine. I'm not sure this will solve OPs problem. The error is related to a error: `Bt is not a valid type`. It doesn't say `mongoose.Types.ObjectId is not a valid type`.

Comment: It helped but now I am getting another error. `TypeError: mongoose__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.models is undefined`

Comment: Ensure that you have properly initialized Mongoose by connecting to your MongoDB database using mongoose.connect. You should do this before defining any models. Can you share your folder structure or code?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well. Turned out I had an unused import of the schema within a file and once removed the error went away. The previous solutions also work however if you find that you dont have any unused schema imports.